# Windows 8 blog reader example

Tags: windows-8

I was trying [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211380.aspx) and I can get the first page up where all the blogs are listed in a GridView. But when I click on one, I'm supposed to see list of blogs with an area to read the blog - instead I keep getting this error below.

collection property __implicit_items is null Line 82 Position 45

I have the following on line 82 in the SplitPage.xaml. It is in the constructor for SplitPage that it fails which looks like this

```
    public SplitPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
```

I went through it and am going through it again to see if I missed something but if there is something I'm obviously doing wrong, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. The actual error was parsing issues with XAML but it was due to which this collection was probably empty. Anyway, I removed this animation XAML at line 82 mentioned in the question and the app works now. Will look at the animation later.

Answer (score 2):

I was working through this sample as well and adjusted the XAML they gave to be

```
<TextBlock.Transitions>
    <TransitionCollection>
        <ContentThemeTransition />
    </TransitionCollection>
</TextBlock.Transitions>
```

which seems to fix the error.

Comment: Had the same issue... Visual Studio didn't complain when I left out the TransitionCollection element but the runtime exception went away after adding it.